# Reorder comma separated sentences into new paragraphs

Tags: database, asp-classic

[image: database screenshot]

Above is a database that i am uploading to a hosting server to pull the data off of it to a website using .asp code in a HTML file. The sensors field gets the data using lookup from another table and can contain multiple values but these values are separated using a comma ",". I was wondering if there was a way either within the database or on the .asp page to get rid of the comma and sort them in a new paragraph or replace the "," with "< br/ >" between each of the sentences

Comment: have you check `replace` methods?

Comment: i didn't know how. I'll do a quick check and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE CHANGE TO ORIGINAL QUESTION**

The original question was in reference to ASP.NET. After providing a thorough answer it transpired that the author was actually using VBScript and Classic ASP. The final update to this answer reflects his change.

I have left my original answer just in case it helps someone else with the same issue as originally asked..

===================================

`Replace` won't be enough if you want to change any of the order; I.E alphabetically.

One way would be to put the Database string into a `list`, splitting it at the comma. you can then output this list in any order you want.

For example.

to Split into a list

```
List<string> myList = yourSensorsString.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

You can then order this however you see fit. Something like:

```
myList.Sort();
```

Then simply go through each of the items, like - where myLbl is perhaps a `label` control on your page

```
foreach ( str in myList) {
    myLbl.Text += str + "<br />";
}
```

Or as separate paragraphs, maybe into a `Literal`

```
   foreach ( str in myList) {
        myLit.Text += "<p>" + str + "</p>";
    }
```

**Update**

This code example above would be placed in your code-behind. You would get your `sensors` string from the database, and then split it into a `list`, then output to the HTML. No need to get your database to perform this sort of logic. 
I have also assumed C# as you never mentioned what flavour of .net you're using.

**Update 2**

After looking at your fiddle, i edited it slightly to show where you can use this sort of code. Also converted my code to VB. Hope this helps. Can't put any more time into this... [Fiddle Is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xR89s/2/)

**Update 3**

The original question was for ASP.NET - as it turns out, it's actually Classic ASP the OP is asking about.

So split your string like this:

```
myList=Split(rsLogbook("FieldName"), ",")
for each str in myList
    document.write(str & "<br />")
next
```

Other than that, I can't help any further - lot of time spent on this :)

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a noob but will i be implementing this code to split the string into my html page or someplace in my database

Comment: Im using VB.net and not using C# and really sorry but i still dont get where im supposed to chuck this in. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xR89s/) Heres the .asp code im using to drag the data from the database if it helps :) Cheers mate

Comment: I used the code and implemented it on the .asp page and im getting an error. Could you look into it please. [link here](http://users9.jabry.com/obdkey/Featuredvehicle.asp)

Comment: Seriously?! You removed my answer? You indicated that you were using ASP.NET - That error in your comment clearly shows you're using Classic ASP - That would warrant and ENTIRELY different code as NONE of what I have provided (which was based on ASP.NET) would work in Classic ASP. I would appreciate you marking this back as correct (as it is correct) - and then asking a new question, indicating that you're using Classic ASP.

Comment: You're also NOT using VB.NET but instead VBScript. If this is a new project I would seriously reconsider the framework and language you're using and perhaps look at asp.net in VB. You'll benefit in the long run.

Comment: I changed it to asp classic now. If you could please help me with this. :)

Comment: see update - I can't help anymore after this. you need to learn about splitting strings in an array, and also how to loop through an array. that should get you up and running