# Spot whats wrong in the code

Tags: database, asp-classic, vbscript

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903828/reorder-comma-seperated-sentences-into-new-paragraphs) yesterday and got an answer. I read through it and thought it would work but after implementing the code to my .asp page im getting an error.

```
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.mdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT TableName.FieldName FROM TableName;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon

'' get string and put into list
Dim myList As List(Of String) = rsLogbook("FieldName").ToString().Split(New () {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()

'' then close all your stuff
rsLogbook.Close
Set rsLogbook = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing

'' Sort your list
myList.Sort();

'' now output to where ever you want.
'' in this case, have an asp.literal control on your page where you want the text and call it myLit
For each sensor in myList
myLit.Text += "<p>" + sensor + "</p>"
Next
%>
```

The error says

> "Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> Dim myList As List(Of String) = rsLogbook("sensors").ToString().Split(New () {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
>   -----------^

I would really appreciate any help with this.

> What i am trying to do here using this code is to pull information off of a database and display it in a webpage using .asp and VB script. I'm using the Response.Write tags in the .asp page to implement the field name that contains the information in the database

**UPDATE**

```
<%
Dim adoCon
Dim rsLogbook
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*accdb, *.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("featuredvehicle.accdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT featuredvehicles.make FROM featuredvehicles;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
Response.Write ("<br>")
Response.Write (rsLogbook("make"))
rsLogbook.Close
Set rsLogbook = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
%>
```

This is the actual code with the database and table names in it as well

Comment: You are taking c# code and trying to re-write in vbscript/ASP? You need to re-write the entire line that the interpreter is pointing to - such constructs, as well as most of the methods aren't going to be available in vbscript.

Comment: could you help me out with reqriting this code in classic asp instead of asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is retrieve a field from the database and Response.Write all rows, you could use something like this. Note that I have removed the VB.NET code to create a List. I also added a WHERE clause to your SQL query in case you don't want empty values (as per the VB.NET) and added an ORDER BY clause to replace the List sort.

```
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.mdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT TableName.FieldName FROM TableName WHERE TableName.FieldName != '' ORDER BY TableName.FieldName ASC;" 'Add order by clause so you don't need to sort the array
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon

Do Until rsLogBook.EOF
    Response.Write(rsLogbook("FieldName")) & "<br />"
    rsLogBook.MoveNext
Loop

rsLogbook.Close
Set rsLogbook = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
```

Comment: Im using .accdb instead of .mdb file now because of some additional features that aren't supported in the .mdb file. Is there a way to edit this code to make it work with .accdb I already tried [adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb")](http://jsfiddle.net/aX4Jg/) and it didnt work out

Comment: If you have Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb") in your connection string, the file DatabaseName.accdb must be in the same folder as this script. Is it?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

/featuredvehicle.asp, line 125

Thats line 3 on your code

Comment: Is your database called DatabaseName.mdb or did you change the connection string to the name of your database? Does the database need a password? You may not be able to open the database if you also have it open in Access.

Comment: the database is called featuredvehicle.accdb and yes i did change it to the database name adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*accdb, *.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("featuredvehicle.accdb") and ill update the top post with the whole VB code i used in my page

Comment: I don't what it could be then. Have you been able to connect to this database in ASP before?

Comment: no. But i managed to form a link to the database using dreamweaver. So ill probably look go through that way. Thanks a lot for your help